# Using generated methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have an EF entity model for my database I'm using with C# and VS2010. The model has an entity called `tblPendingMessages`, which I use to create messages to be dispatched periodically by my SQL Server agent. It's pretty simple.

EF appears to have generated a method of the entity `tblPendingMessages` called `CreatetblPendingMessage`. The method looks perfect for adding new pending messages, but its parameters include the primary key, which is an identity column. Normally, I'd use `null`, but Intellisense doesn't allow it, it wants an `int`...

How do I do this?

------- Edit

I did some more research. EF doesn't seem to be very popular, but since I'm just starting out, it seems like going with the most current wave makes sense.

Anyway, the 'CreatetblPendingMessage' method is a factory method, used to create a single 'tblPendingMessage' "row" instance. That new "row" still has to be added to the tblPendingMessages object, and then changes saved. I found some code examples, and here's what I ended up doing (be kind, I'm still a c# newby....):

```
    private void NotifyWorkbookError(List<string> MsgLst)
    {            
        string msgs = string.Join(@"<br />",MsgLst.Select(i=>i.ToArray()));
        string finalHTML = GetHTML(3).Replace("#WBMessage#",msgs);
        using (CPASEntities ctx=new CPASEntities())
        {
            tblPendingMessage m = new tblPendingMessage 
            {   
                Recipient=@"jamesshaffer@n.com",
                MessageBody=finalHTML,
                MessageGenerated=DateTime.Now,
                MessageFormat="HTML",
                MessageCC=@"CPAS_TIMESHEET_AUDITOR@N.COM"
            };
            ctx.tblPendingMessages.AddObject(m);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    private string GetHTML(int MessageID)
    {
        string htMsg;
        using (CPASEntities ctx = new CPASEntities())
        {
            tblHTML h = (from ht in ctx.tblHTMLs
                         where ht.HTMLID == MessageID
                         select ht).FirstOrDefault();
            htMsg = h.HTMLCode;
        }
        htMsg = htMsg.Replace("#ID#", TimesheetID.ToString());
        htMsg = htMsg.Replace("#VendorName#", VendorFullName);
        htMsg = htMsg.Replace("#WeekStart#", WeekStartDate.ToShortDateString());
        htMsg = htMsg.Replace("#SubmittedBy#", Creator);
        htMsg = htMsg.Replace("#SubmittedOnDate#", DateTime.Parse(CreateDate).ToShortDateString());
        htMsg = htMsg.Replace("#ModifiedBy#", Modifier);
        htMsg = htMsg.Replace("#ModifiedOnDate#", DateTime.Parse(ModDate).ToShortDateString());
        htMsg = htMsg.Replace("#WorkbookStatus#", CurrentStatus);
        htMsg = htMsg.Replace("#NewWorkbookStatus#", CurrentStatus);
        htMsg = htMsg.Replace("#AbsoluteURL#", link);
        return htMsg;
    }
```

Comment: Code please so we can see

Comment: I'd imagine that you could just not set that variable, or put in whatever you want knowing that the DB is going to overwrite it later.

Comment: Is the `StoreGeneratedPattern` property for the primary key set to "Identity"? What code generation mechanism are you using?  It's the "Custom Tool" property of the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `-1` or `0` as primary key value for `tblPendingMessages` entity (entity will not be submitted to database - it will be created in memory). Also you can create your own more handy method which will use default primary key value, because entities are declared in partial classes:

```
public partial class tblPendingMessages
{
    public static tblPendingMessages CreatetblPendingMessage(string foo, int bar)
    {
        return CreatetblPendingMessage(-1, foo, bar);
    }
}
```